# Force login/user creation through cloud identity for googel analytics

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-cloud-identity

Is there a way to force the user creation and login through cloud identity and don't allow marketing to add users to analytics as they please?

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly, but if you have a Cloud Identity/Workspace account for, say, `example.com`, you can:

1. [Migrate](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/migrating-consumer-accounts) or [evict](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/evicting-consumer-accounts) all existing `@example.com` consumer accounts.
2. [Prevent new consumer account sign-ups](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/best-practices-for-federating#prevent_new_consumer_account_sign-ups) for `@example.com`
3. [Set a policy in Marketing Platform](https://support.google.com/marketingplatform/answer/9014058?hl=en) to only allow members from `@example.com`

In combination, this should have the desired effect.

If you're using a corporate, TLS-inspecting proxy, you can also [block access to consumer accounts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1668854?hl=en).

Comment: Thank you, Johannes. I was aware of 1 and 2 but did not know that you can do the rest through the marketing platform. Good idea. Thank you